# Ifelse for matrix in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
cenarios = 100 #

tamanho = 10000
prob_sin = 0.02
sev_med = 10000

replicacoes_ind = matrix(NA, tamanho, cenarios)

replicacoes_sev = matrix(NA, tamanho, cenarios)

SAg = array(NA, cenarios)

quant_sin = array(NA, cenarios)

u = matrix(data=runif(tamanho*cenarios, 0, 1), nrow=tamanho, ncol=cenarios)
ifelse(u <= prob_sin, {replicacoes_ind = 1; replicacoes_sev = rexp(1,rate = 1/sev_med)}, {replicacoes_ind = 0; replicacoes_sev = 0})
```

However in my last line (`ifelse`) what I intended to do is: if each element of the matrix `u` is <= than `prob_sin`, then the respective element of the `replicacoes_ind` matrix is ​​equal to 1 and the respective element of the `replicacoes_sev` matrix follows a number random. Otherwise, 0 in the respective elements. However, it assigns 1 or 0 to the matrices and transforms them into numbers.

How can I make this condition for each element of the matrices involved?

Comment: I think you need to save the selection of `sel <- u <= prob_sin` then use that to subset/replace the other matrices. E.g. `replicacoes_ind[sel] <- 1` etc

Comment: It would have been easier if you reduced `tamanho`, `cenarios` to something small i.e 5 or 10 and show the expected output by using `set.seed` while producing `u`.

Comment: I've never found `ifelse` that need braces `{ ... }` to be clear code. While it can work, it seems to be compacting too much at the expense of readability and therefore maintainability and bug-hunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using a much smaller example set (and a seed for reproducibility):

```r
cenarios = 5
tamanho = 6
sev_med = 6
replicacoes_ind = matrix(NA, tamanho, cenarios)
replicacoes_sev = matrix(NA, tamanho, cenarios)
SAg = array(NA, cenarios)
quant_sin = array(NA, cenarios)

set.seed(42)
u = matrix(data=runif(tamanho*cenarios, 0, 1), nrow=tamanho, ncol=cenarios)
u
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
# [1,] 0.9148060 0.7365883 0.9346722 0.4749971 0.08243756
# [2,] 0.9370754 0.1346666 0.2554288 0.5603327 0.51421178
# [3,] 0.2861395 0.6569923 0.4622928 0.9040314 0.39020347
# [4,] 0.8304476 0.7050648 0.9400145 0.1387102 0.90573813
# [5,] 0.6417455 0.4577418 0.9782264 0.9888917 0.44696963
# [6,] 0.5190959 0.7191123 0.1174874 0.9466682 0.83600426
```

For grins, I'll set a limit of 0.15 so that we can replace a few of the values:

```r
prob_sin <- 0.15
ind <- (u <= prob_sin)
ind
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

From here, we can generate the 0s and 1s in one step:

```r
replicacoes_ind <- +ind
replicacoes_ind
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    1    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    1    0    0
```

The second matrix is about the same:

```r
replicacoes_sev[ind] <- rexp(sum(ind), rate = 1/sev_med)
replicacoes_sev
#      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
# [1,]   NA       NA       NA        NA 41.07943
# [2,]   NA 25.00878       NA        NA       NA
# [3,]   NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
# [4,]   NA       NA       NA 0.1728925       NA
# [5,]   NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
# [6,]   NA       NA 7.170642        NA       NA
replicacoes_sev[!ind] <- 0
replicacoes_sev
#      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
# [1,]    0  0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 41.07943
# [2,]    0 25.00878 0.000000 0.0000000  0.00000
# [3,]    0  0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000  0.00000
# [4,]    0  0.00000 0.000000 0.1728925  0.00000
# [5,]    0  0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000  0.00000
# [6,]    0  0.00000 7.170642 0.0000000  0.00000
```